# How to add data from database table to ListView C# Xamarin Android App

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, android-listview, xamarin

Few days ago I asked how to share data between activities and one user told me to use SQLite, so I did. I want to let user click on button in the MainLayout which will redirect him to AddTaskLayout where he can add task name, and by pressing Save button app will redirect him back to MainLayout where his task will be listed in ListView.

So far, I created database, table and everything that I need. My question is: How to add data stored in database table to ListView? Every answer I've found was written in Java so searching old StackOverflow questions wasn't so helpful :/

Here's the code:

My DBRepository is class that represents creating database, creating table, inserting data to table and getting that same data:

```
public class DBRepository
{

    public void CreateDatabase()
    {
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath
            (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "database.db3");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
    }

    public void CreateTable()
    {
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath
           (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "database.db3");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
        db.CreateTable<ToDoTasks>();
    }

    public string InsertRecord(string task)
    {
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath
           (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "database.db3");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
        ToDoTasks item = new ToDoTasks();
        item.Task = task;
        db.Insert(item);
        return task;
    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath
           (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "database.db3");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
        string output = "";
        var table = db.Table<ToDoTasks>();
        foreach(var item in table)
        {
            output += item;

        }            
        return output;
    }
}
```

ToDoTasks class where I create table:

```
[Table("ToDo")]
public class ToDoTasks
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Task { get; set; }
}
```

My AddTaskActivity represents second Layout where user enters task name:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{

    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AddTask);

    //define buttons
    Button save, cancel;
    save = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.save);
    cancel = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cancel);

    save.Click += save_click;
    cancel.Click += cancel_click;
}

private void save_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DBRepository dbr = new DBRepository();
    EditText name = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.taskName);
    //enter user's input(task name) to table

    var result = dbr.InsertRecord(name.Text);
    StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
}

private void cancel_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
}
```

My MainActivity where I want to populate listView:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set view
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    //create database if it doesn't exist
    DBRepository dbr = new DBRepository();
    dbr.CreateDatabase();

    //create table (if it doesn't exist)
    dbr.CreateTable();

    //Define buttons
    Button addTask;
    ListView list;
    addTask = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.addTask);
    addTask.Click += addTask_click;
}             

private void addTask_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartActivity(typeof(AddTaskActivity));
}
```

I really appreciate your help. I know these are pretty basic questions, but someone have to ask them for himself and many others (future) C# android developers. Thanks!

**//////////////////////**

**UPDATE:** I checked Johan's answer as correct, but here is (in my case) correct code:

I needed to change GetData() method to return List (not object as before) and then show that List in ListView. Here's the code:

```
    You helped me a lot, but I had to make few changes, so here they are for the record:
```

In DBRepository needed to change GetData() method to this:

```
    public List<string> GetData()
    {
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath
           (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "database.db3");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in db.Table<ToDoTasks>())
        {
            var zad = item.Task.ToString();

            data.Add(zad);
        }
        return data;

    }
```

And then, in MainActivity where is code for ListView only add this:

```
    var items = dbr.GetData();
        var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);

        listView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
```

I hope it will help someone else in the future. Thanks once again guys.

Comment: Xamarin has multiple samples that demonstrate how to do this - look at Tasky: https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/Tasky/TaskyAndroid

Comment: @Jason: Tasky wasn't very helpful, too complex code for a starter like me :/

Comment: Firstly, you will need to change your `GetData()` method to return a list of `ToDoTasks` (ie. `IEnumerable<ToDoTasks>`).  Once that is done, you will need to use an adapter (I think the `SimpleAdapter` should work fine for your initial version, might want to create your own one at some point).  Then you will need to set the adapter to the `ListView`.

Comment: what I mean by 'set the adapter to the ListView', I meant you need to set the adapter on the ListView (ie. not entirely sure about syntax, but it's either `listView.SetAdapter(adapter)` or `listView.Adapter = adapter`)

Comment: @Johan: Can you show me how to use IEnumerable, please?

EDIT: So I need to change public string GetData() to public IEnumerable<ToDoTasks> GetData() and return string output?

Comment: @matejcro you could use any collection object (`IList<T>`, `List<T>`, etc).  Have you used any collection type object before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comments, you would need to make the following changes.

```
public List<ToDoTasks> GetData()
{
    string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "database.db3");
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
    return db.Table<ToDoTasks>().ToList();
}
```

Then in your Activity, where you have a `ListView` in your  you can do the following

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   base.OnCreate(bundle);

   // Set view
   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

   //create database if it doesn't exist
   DBRepository dbr = new DBRepository();
   dbr.CreateDatabase();

   //create table (if it doesn't exist)
   dbr.CreateTable();

   var items = dbr.GetData();
   var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Android.Resource.Id.ListView);
   listView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
}
```

If your Activity inherits from `ListActivity`  you can just do the following

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   base.OnCreate(bundle);

   // Set view
   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

   //create database if it doesn't exist
   DBRepository dbr = new DBRepository();
   dbr.CreateDatabase();

   //create table (if it doesn't exist)
   dbr.CreateTable();

   var items = dbr.GetData();
   ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
}
```

I have taken parts of the code from the examples provided by Xamarin, which can be found here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/